# Float Right Inside A CSS-Table Cell

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

I've a question regarding a layout I'm making. I want to make a simple horizontal navigation menu and I'm starting out with this:
https://jsfiddle.net/74596pc8/

However, when I try to float the menu inside the 2 column to the right the margins of the first get all messed up, like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/33pf48u2/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="top-bar">


        <div class="grid">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col3">
                    LOGO
                </div>

                <div class="col9">
                    <nav class="right" style="height:55px;">
                        <div class="menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>     

     </div>

    <div class="home-bar">

        <div class="grid">
             <div class="row">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="home-posts">

        <div class="grid">

        </div>

    </div>
```

Grid:

```
.grid {
   margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; }

  .col {
    display: table-cell; }

 /* .row-padded {
    margin-left: -1rem;
    margin-right: -1rem; }

  .row-padded .row {
    border-spacing: 1rem 0; } } */

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .col1 {
    display: table-cell;   
    width: 8.333333%; }
 ....
```

The Applied CSS:

```
/* Nav Menu
---------------------------------------*/
html ul,li{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right{
float:right;
}
```

Please advise on why this is and how to fix it :)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, for explaining, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using float right you can use text align: right property, it will give you the same result.

```
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ahmer. I am aware of  this, but I would like to learn more about the diplay:table property and how it behaves, thus like to know why a float affects the alignment of the first column